# Exporting PHP code from with a PHP file

Tags: php, export

I need to practically generate a .PHP file using a PHP script or PHP command. The file generate will contain the following code:

```
<?php
class TextToSpeech {
    public $mp3data;
    function __construct($text="") {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $lang_en="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}";
            $lang_ro="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ro&q={$text}";
            $lang_fr="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q={$text}";
            $language=$lang_en;
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents($language);
        }
    }

    function setText($text) {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $en="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}";
            $ro="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ro&q={$text}";
            $fr="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q={$text}";
            $lang=$en;
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents($lang);
            return  $this->mp3data;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function saveToFile($filename) {
        $filename = trim($filename);
        if(!empty($filename)) {
            return file_put_contents($filename,$this->mp3data);
        } else { return false; }
    }
}
?>
```

I want to do this because I want to have multiple choices regarding the language:

```
$language=$lang_en;
```

and

```
$lang=$en;
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to solve a problem in a very bad way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your question is here. Generating a PHP file is no different than generating any other kind of file. Build a string of the source code you want to write, then a simple `file_put_contents('filename.php', $contents);` will do the trick.

**Edit**: Where are `$en` and `$lang_en` coming from? Also, could these not be passed as parameters to the function? Why must they be hard-coded?

```
$contents = '
<?php
   // your PHP here

';

file_put_contents('filename.php', $contents);
```

You may also want to read up on heredocs for large blocks of text, but unfortunately those will replace your variables unless you escape them all with a backslash.

Comment: The code works fine but i want to make 3 different ones:

First one with:
$language=$lang_en;
$lang=$en;

Second one with:
$language=$lang_ro;
$lang=$ro;

Third with:
$language=$lang_fr;
$lang=$fr;

Comment: You do it like any other string. $contents = '<?php ...'; Check my edits I'll make them now.

Comment: I tried but the code contains special characters like ;'"> and so. That's why it won't work

Comment: If you put your string between single quotes it should be ok (you will have to escape the single quotes)